# Use post variable with querySelector

Tags: node.js, dom, puppeteer, queryselector

I'm facing an issue trying to scrape datas on the web with puppeteer and querySelector.

I have a nodeJS WebServer that handle a post query, and then call a function to scrape the datas. I'm sending 2 parameters (postBlogUrl & postDomValue).

PostDomValue will contains as string the selector I'm trying to fetch datas from, for example:
[itemprop='articleBody'].

If I manually suggest the selector ([itemprop='articleBody']), everything is working well, I'm able to retrieve datas, but if i use the postDomValue var, nothing is returned.

I already tried to escape the var using CSS.escape(postDomValue), but no luck.

```
fetchBlogContent: async function(postBlogUrl, postDomValue) {
try {
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(postBlogUrl, {
    waitUntil: 'load'
  })
  let description = await page.evaluate(() => {
    //This works return document.querySelector("[itemprop='articleBody']").innerHTML;
    //This won't return document.querySelector(postDomValue).innerHTML;
  })
  return description
} catch (err) {
  // handle err
  return err;
 }
}
```

Comment: ```document.querySelector(`${postDomValue}`).innerHTML```

Comment: Unfortunately I did already try this method, but keep returning an empty result

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify(postDomValue)`?

Comment: Indeed, I also tried

Comment: Are you sure `postDomValue` evaluates to `[itemprop='articleBody']`

Comment: If it does, then do `JSON.parse()` on `postDomValue` when calling `fetchBlogContent()` and doing `JSON.stringify` again

Comment: Yes I am, no chance it evaluates something else, I also placed a console.log right before and the value is correct. Also, everything is working well using Chrome console

Comment: Ok I'm giving a try right now

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seems to do the trick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230047/discussion-between-f1rstsurf-and-fortunee).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const description = await page.evaluate((value) => 
    document.querySelector(value).innerHTML, JSON.stringify(postDomValue));
```

See docs on how to pass args to `page.evaluate()` in [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the issue may be that you try to use a variable declared in the Node.js context inside an argument function of `page.evaluate()` that is executed in the browser context. In such cases, you need to transfer the value of a variable as an additional argument:

```js
  let description = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
    return document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML;
  }, postDomValue);
```

See more in [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

Comment: Thanks for your help, so what should I set the selector var with ?

Comment: I tried the code snippet, but it still returns an empty result

Comment: `selector` variable will be automatically set equal to `postDomValue` when you call `page.evaluate()` this way.

Comment: Lol I answered this in the chat

Comment: Then you can add an answer so that it could be accepted)

Comment: Thank you so much guys, both of your answers are working, but the one suggested by fortunee also work with my other json values

Comment: Yeah, @fortunee has paid much more attention to your issue)